# Javascript dropdown updates the price based on the users selection version 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu

I needed some help updating the price on a page based on a dropdown selection.

This is what code with some help we came up with:

```
    var price = new Array('','$2.00','$45.00','$60.00');
    $(function(){
        $('select[name=material]').change(function(){
          document.getElementById('pprice').innerHTML = price[$(this).val()];
        }); 

        // Trigger on dom ready
        $('select[name=material]').change();
    });
```

Which works if my dropdown is structured like this:

```
    <select name="material">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="1">Wood</option>
        <option value="2">Plastic</option>
        <option value="3">Metal</option>
    </select>
```

But if for any reason the the dropdown was to be like this:

```
    <select name="material">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="3">Metal</option>
        <option value="4">Cloth</option>
        <option value="5">UPVC</option>
    </select>
```

it would not work (because the value option is not 1,2,3). The value is the id for the material. Hope this makes sense and that someone can help me to get this working.

Thanks
Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select price using the `selectedIndex` of your `<select>`:

```
var price = new Array('','$2.00','$45.00','$60.00');
$(function(){
    $('select[name=material]').change(function(){
        document.getElementById('pprice').innerHTML = price[this.selectedIndex];
    });

    // Trigger on dom ready
    $('select[name=material]').change();
});
```

Or, use an object instead of an array for `price`:

```
var price = {
    "4": "$2.00",
    "5": "$45.00",
    "6": "$60.00"
};
$(function(){
    $('select[name=material]').change(function(){
        document.getElementById('pprice').innerHTML = price[$(this).val()];
    });

    // Trigger on dom ready
    $('select[name=material]').change();
});
```

Comment: UPDATE

Once again thank you for all the responses. Gilly I think your solution is the best way to handle the updating of price on the page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the price based on the value, and using that as the item from your price array... but your price array only has 4 values. In your second select, you're asking it to return price[4] or price[5], which would cause an error.

Change this:

```
var price = new Array('','$2.00','$45.00','$60.00');
```

To this:

```
var price = new Array('','$2.00','$45.00','$60.00','$cloth price','$upvc price');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLRWK/) here.**

**EDIT: Updated method** (with minimal change to your existing layout/logic)

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name=material]').change(function() {
        var price = $(this).val().split("_");
        $("#id").html(price[0]);
        $("#price").html("$" + price[1]);
    });
});
```

**HTML** (adding the price to each option value, split by "_" in JS)

```
<select name="material">
    <option value="0_0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="1_2">Wood</option>
    <option value="2_2">Plastic</option>
    <option value="3_45">Metal</option>
</select>

<select name="material">
    <option value="0_0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="3_60">Metal</option>
    <option value="4_50">Cloth</option>
    <option value="5_80">UPVC</option>
</select>

<div>ID: <span id="id">TBD</span><br />Price: <span id="price">TBD</span></div>
```

Comment: yep, thats the exact problem I found too, but is there an efficient way to ammend the code so that it works with the second dropdown, without adding extra values to the price array.

Comment: What are the prices for the second select? I also think there's a better way to do this, and you can keep the price as part of each option's value. Did you consider this?

Comment: I thought about setting the price, as the dropdown v alue but just in terms of the application its easier to work with the id.

Comment: Are the prices for each select the same? So Metal in #1 costs $60 and in #2 costs $2?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** [Here is a jsfiddle with updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/FZ9NZ/1/) to get your single price array to work:

Your price arrayhas a length of 4 and starts at index 0.

Your first option must have a value of '0' or it will return undefined from the price array:

```
<select name="material">
    <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="1">Wood</option>
    <option value="2">Plastic</option>
    <option value="3">Metal</option>
</select>
```

When you set your option values from 3 to 5, you are trying to access non-existent indexes outside the bounds of your price array.

Comment: the above: <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option> was working without the value being set to 0.

Comment: How would I handle, a dropdown if it was structured like this:
  <select name="material">
   <option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
   <option value="901">Carbon Fibre</option>
   <option value="2002">Glass</option>
   <option value="6242">Cotton</option>
  </select>
in an efficient way without having an array of 6242 prices?

Comment: no it will produce 'undefined' as the output because you would be trying access the price array without an index

Comment: yep correct my mistake i didn't see undefined because I used:


   if (typeof metalprice[$(this).val()] == "undefined"){metalprice[$(this).val()]='from $1.00'}

Comment: Thanks

Paul and BumbleB2na. Decided to go with pauls solution.

Many thanks