# Drop down price update

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, price

I am trying to build an app that let people choose a license and the price is different for different licenses. I want a real-time price update on the page of the product. Here is the reference that I took for the below code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740218

Code:

```js
<script type="text/javaScript">
    var price = {"3":"11","2":"500","1":"1000"};
 $(function() {
        $('select[name=dropdown_price_change]').change(function() {
            document.getElementById('price_disp').innerHTML = price[$(this).val()];
        });

        // Trigger on dom ready
        $('select[name=dropdown_price_change]').change();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="product-price" id="price_disp">
    <form class="cart nobottommargin clearfix" method="get">
        <div class="quantity clearfix">
            <select id="dropdown_price_change" name="dropdown_price_change" class="form-control">
                <option value="3">Personal License</option>
                <option value="2">Small Firm License</option>
                <option value="1">Enterprise or Developer License</option>
            </select>
        </div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: So, what's your question? And, how about you reformat the code in your question with proper indentation?

Comment: `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML` and frankly, you should probably be using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHtml` should be `innerHTML` and frankly, you should probably be using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` in this case anyway since the values of the `select` don't contain any HTML.

Also, you shouldn't trigger the `change` function on document ready because the user will never get to see and use the dropdown list that way.

Lastly, add a "dummy" choice to the list as the default choice so that the user must change the value if they want to select "Personal License" from the list. Without this, the change event won't trigger because that was the default choice in the first place.

```js
var price = {"3":"11","2":"500","1":"1000"};

$(function(){
  $('select[name=dropdown_price_change]').change(function(){
    document.getElementById('price_disp').textContent = price[$(this).val()];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-price" id="price_disp">
  <form class="cart nobottommargin clearfix" method="get">
    <div class="quantity clearfix">
      <select id="dropdown_price_change" name="dropdown_price_change" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value="3">Personal License</option>
        <option value="2">Small Firm License</option>
        <option value="1">Enterprise or Developer License</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```